# scrape a div with auto generated class with python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Hello I'm trying to scrape some questions from a web forum

I am able to scrape questions with a

> find_elements_by_xpath

it's something like this :

```
questions = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="autu-generated"]//div[@class="corpus"]//div[@class="body-bd"]//p')
```

I made a diagram so you can understand my situation :
[image]

my problem is if I didn't specify the auto-generated class in the XPath it's gonna return all the values from the other divs (which I don't want )

and writing the auto-generated class manually like I did to test isn't a valid idea because I'm scraping multiple questions with multiple classes

do you guys have any ideas on how to resolve this problem ??

[here](https://forum.bouyguestelecom.fr/questions/2818213-debit-descendant-faible-fibre) is the web forum

thank you

my code :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time
from fastparquet.parquet_thrift.parquet.ttypes import TimeUnit
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/ossama/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver')
page = 1
#looping in pages
while page <= 10:
      driver.get('https://forum.bouyguestelecom.fr/questions/browse?flow_state=published&order=created_at.desc&page='+str(page)+'&utf8=✓&search=&with_category%5B%5D=2483')
      # checking to click the pop-up cookies interfaces
      if page == 1:
                   #waiting 10s for the pop-up to show up before accepting it
                   time.sleep(10)
                   driver.find_element_by_id('popin_tc_privacy_button_3').click()
                   # store all the links in a list
                   #question_links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="corpus"]//a[@class="content_permalink"]')
                   links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="corpus"]//a[@class="content_permalink"]')
                   forum_links= []
                   for link in links:
                       value = link.get_attribute("href")
                       print(value)
                       forum_links.append(value)

      else:
          links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="corpus"]//a[@class="content_permalink"]')
          for link in links:
              value = link.get_attribute("href")
              print(value)
              forum_links.append(value)
              q_df = pd.DataFrame(forum_links)
              q_df.to_csv('forum_links.csv')
      page = page + 1

for link in forum_links:
    driver.get(link)
    #time.sleep(5)
    #driver.find_element_by_id('popin_tc_privacy_button_3').click()
    questions = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="corpus"]//div[@class="body-bd"]//p')
    authors = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="corpus"]//div[@class="metadata"]//dl[@class="author-name"]//dd//a')
    dates = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="corpus"]//div[@class="metadata"]//dl[@class="date"]//dd')
    questions_list = []
    for question in questions:
        for author in authors:
            for date in dates:
                questions_list.append([question.text, author.text, date.text])
                print(question.text)
                print(author.text)
                print(date.text)
                q_df = pd.DataFrame(questions_list)
                q_df.to_csv('colrow.csv')
```

Comment: Will be great to see where your code failing, so please consider to post  your code as well.

Comment: thanks for your reply , code added !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improved XPATH, and removed second loop.

```
page = 1
while page <= 10:
    driver.get(
        'https://forum.bouyguestelecom.fr/questions/browse?flow_state=published&order=created_at.desc&page=' + str(
            page) + '&utf8=✓&search=&with_category%5B%5D=2483')
    driver.maximize_window()
    print("Page  url: " + driver.current_url)
    time.sleep(1)

    if page == 1:
        AcceptButton = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'popin_tc_privacy_button_3')
        AcceptButton.click()

    questions = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="corpus"]//a[@class="content_permalink"]')
    
    for count, item in enumerate(questions, start=1):
        print(str(count) + ": question detail:")
        questionfount = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                            "(//div[@class='corpus']//a[@class='content_permalink'])[" + str(
                                                count) + "]")
        questionfount.click()
        questionInPage = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
            (By.XPATH, "(//p[@class='old-h1']//following::div[contains(@__uid__, "
                       "'dim')]//div[@class='corpus']//a["
                       "@class='content_permalink'])[1]")))
        author = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
            (By.XPATH, "(//p[@class='old-h1']//following::div[contains(@__uid__, 'dim')]//div["
                       "@class='corpus']//div[contains(@class, 'metadata')]//dl["
                       "@class='author-name']//a)[1]")))
        date = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
            (By.XPATH, "(//p[@class='old-h1']//following::div[contains(@__uid__, 'dim')]//div["
                       "@class='corpus']//div[contains(@class, 'metadata')]//dl[@class='date']//dd)[1]")))

        print(questionInPage.text)
        print(author.text)
        print(date.text)
        print(
            "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
        driver.back()
        driver.refresh()
    page = page + 1

driver.quit()
```

**Output (in Console):**

```
Page  url: https://forum.bouyguestelecom.fr/questions/browse?flow_state=published&order=created_at.desc&page=1&utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=&with_category%5B%5D=2483
1: question detail:
Comment annuler ma commande bbox
ELHADJI
17 novembre 2021
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2: question detail:
BBOX adsl : Interruption Service Internet ?
GABRIELA
17 novembre 2021
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: i appericiate your effort thank you so much , q : are you using firefox driver cause i've got some errors running this code ?

Comment: No, I am using chrome driver. What error you received? I have used pycharm formatting, that might have caused you issue.

Comment: it's working now , that's a great job thank you so much i only had to change the questionInpage xpath to  get me the question text not it's title

Comment: ` (By.XPATH, "(//p[@class='old-h1']//following::div[contains(@__uid__, "
                       "'dim')]//div[@class='corpus']//div[@class='body-bd'])[1]"))) `

Answer (score 0):

to overcome this issue i found that the div with auto-generated class had a uid
so here is what the xpath looks like now :

```
 questions = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@__uid__="dim2"]//div[@class="corpus"]//div[@class="body-bd"]//p')
```

sometimes we just gotta focus right !

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve? Question, author and date detail from 1 to 10 pages ? right?

Comment: the while loop from 1 to 10 page is to get the links inside of <a href="link"> then the second loop to go to each question page and get the question author and date

Comment: Ok.I also spent some time on your problem, posting here as an answer. You can see if it helps you.